# Flask, serving a React application: cannot refresh "pages"

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

So I am serving a index.html file from Flask.
The index.html file comes from a built project using: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

I have a couple routes setup in the React app, for example:
"/users"
and "/contracts"

When I refresh one of these routes, I get a 404 from flask, but while "clicking" on links found on the site, they work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are clicking the links in the interface, React is re-rendering the page without any server-side intervention, and then updating the route in the URL bar. When loading however, you are making that route request to the server direct, and Flask does not have that route registered.

Simplest way is to register these routes in the decorator for the function serving your homepage view

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/users')
@app.route('/contracts')
def home_page():
```

If there are many many routes, you may want to use the [catch-all URL pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/).

Answer (score 0):

Specifying every route is too prone to error.  Here is a more general solution.

Add an error handler to catch 404:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def handle_404(e):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect(f'/?request_path={quote_plus(request.path)}')
    return e
```

The error handler will redirect to the home page, where your React works, passing the actual requested request_path as a parameter.

In your view handler do this:

```
@app.route('/')
def public_page_index(request_path=None):
    return render_template('index.html', 
        request_path=request.args.get('request_path', ''))
```

The index.html template will create a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="request_path" value="{{request_path}}">
```

Then the actual React path will be available for your React code to respond to.  This is what I've done in my Home page component, using jquery and useHistory().

```
useEffect(() => {
    // find if server refresh needs history
    const $request_path = $('input[name=request_path]');
    const val = $request_path.val();
    if (val) {
        $request_path.val("");
        history.push(val);
        return;
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both previous answers , and at the end I found a general solution :

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../client/build', static_url_path='/')
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
@app.errorhandler(404)
def catch_all(path):
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```